# How to take user input and put it to structure in Go?

Tags: go

I am pretty new in Go. I have next code in Python, where I am getting all test cases in **prepare_tests** function. I need the same thing in Go.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from typing import List

TestCase = namedtuple("TestCase", ["number_of_purchased_items", "prices"])


def prepare_tests() -> List[TestCase]:
    tests = []
    cases_amount = int(input())
    for _ in range(cases_amount):
        number_of_purchased_items = int(input())
        prices = [int(price) for price in input().split(maxsplit=number_of_purchased_items + 1)]
        test_case = TestCase(number_of_purchased_items, prices)
        tests.append(test_case)
    return tests
```

Input( where 2 - test_cases amount, then 6 - numOfPurchasedItems, 2 2 2 3 3 3 - list

```
2
6
2 2 2 3 3 3
7
1 1 2 2 3 3 5
```

Output

```
[TestCase(number_of_purchased_items=6, prices=[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), TestCase(number_of_purchased_items=7, prices=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5])]
```

I tried to write the same in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type testCase struct {
    numberOfPurchasedItems int
    prices                 []int
}

func prepareTests() []testCase {
    var tests []testCase

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    scanner.Scan()
    casesAmount, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return tests
    }

    for i := 0; i < casesAmount; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        numberOfPurchasedItems, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            return tests
        }

        scanner.Scan()
        pricesStr := scanner.Text()

        var prices []int
        for _, priceStr := range strings.Split(pricesStr, " ") {
            price, err := strconv.Atoi(priceStr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                return tests
            }
            prices = append(prices, price)
        }

        tests = append(tests, testCase{numberOfPurchasedItems, prices})
    }

    return tests
}
```

Output in Go:

```
[{6 [2]} {2 [2]}]
```

Comment: I've edited out your question about `collections.Counter` -- you should open a new question for that, because the answers will be unrelated to the primary topic of this question.

Comment: It seems you were able to take user input and put it to structure, so what's left?

Answer (score 0):

you don`t need

```
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
```

so just delete that code

```
type testCase struct {
    numberOfPurchasedItems int
    prices                 []int
}

func prepareTests() []testCase {
    var tests []testCase

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    //scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    scanner.Scan()
    casesAmount, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return tests
    }

    for i := 0; i < casesAmount; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        numberOfPurchasedItems, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            return tests
        }

        scanner.Scan()
        pricesStr := scanner.Text()

        var prices []int
        for _, priceStr := range strings.Split(pricesStr, " ") {
            price, err := strconv.Atoi(priceStr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error:", err)
                return tests
            }
            prices = append(prices, price)
        }

        tests = append(tests, testCase{numberOfPurchasedItems, prices})
    }

    return tests
}
```

Comment: I already did, thank you. But now I have problem while reading large input(200_000-length input for pricesStr).

Comment: Set big size buffer using scanner.Buffer or more low level API
For example use "Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)" read some buffer size and search "\n",  if not find "\n" append to cache buffer, if find "\n" return cache buffer

Comment: but... I think bufio.NewReader should suffice.